# javadoc not found in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

I have a jar as dependency in my project. In the build path for this jar I click that little triangle and there I can give the javadoc the location for this library. The "validate" button tells me that my location is most likely valid. The javadoc is still not shown. The hoover over in the java editor is switched on as well. I added the javadoc as jar and as well tried to unzip it to a location and point to that location.

What else can I check?

Answer (score 0):

One factor that can affect this (though who knows why on Earth this is the case) is the order in which the JAR file is listed in the libraries.

Try bringing that library to the top of the stack in the Build Path dialogue "Order & Export".